# Safari on iPhone not loading image (file) from Google Drive

Tags: iphone, image, safari, drive

I am trying to load an image located on Google Drive onto a webpage.
It works for Chrome on desktop and mobile device (iOS and Android).
It also works on Safari on desktop (MAC OS).

However, when loading it from Safari on iPhone (iOS), it does NOT work.

is there any specific settings or adjustment needed for iOS Safari?

iOS version 16.1.1
Model iPhone 13

Below is the html code:

```
<br> <br> 
<b> Google Drive </b> <br>
<img id='cover-photo' src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=<id for the photo on Google Drive>" alt='testcoverimage' width="200" height="200">
<br> <br>
```

Comment: Google Drive isn't really a good choice for image hosting.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in iOS Safari. My solution is upload the image to Imgur, then set the source to the image url: `src="https://i.imgur.com/XXXXXXX.png"`